# How to get object's original prefab in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get original object(prefab)'s reference of the cloned object.

```
GameObject bullet = Object.Instantiate(bulletObject) as GameObject;
```

Then the bullet must know its original object.

How do I identify the original object from a prefab instance?

Like...

```
if(bullet.getOriginalPrefab() == bulletObject) {}
```

Comment: From the Editor or standalone build?

Comment: Uhm.. I'm sorry i can't understand what you means...

Comment: Is this for editor plugin or do you expect it to run/work when you build the project?

Comment: Maybe the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You need hold your original prefab in master controller and then clone by this. Main logic is that you always have prefab in master controller with base parameters.

Comment: Well.. i'm writing a object pool which can pooling multiple type of object. 
So i classify manage type of  each  object  to another list (actually active list and inactive list pair for each object prefab). Each list was distinguished by prefab reference. But I don't know how to release it. ReleaseObject(GameObject targetObject) must know it's original object (prefab) reference to find it's list (actually inactive list). Because release means that the release target object move active list to inactive list.

Comment: Then you means that i must hold original prefab in master controller and use this for distinguish the release object's original prefab?

Comment: Logic of prefab is that you can't create clear new prefab by your current prefab. It also work with classes, not with prefabs. I only see two option to do this:
1) hold prefab name to load it from resources;
2) hold clear prefab in game to clone it.

Comment: Uhm..  if possible may i have some additional explanation about 'Clear Prefab'? I still can't catch the 'clear' means..